# Guidelines for migrating to AngularFire 0.5 from 0.3

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am planning to migrate a rather large application from AngularFire 0.3 to the newest 0.5.x. 
Are there any guidelines/gotchas/tips/experiences/checklist that you can share, that would help make the migration smoother?

P.S:FYI, the application uses automatic three way angularfire binding as opposed to explicit save/updates and I plan to retain the automatic three way binding with 0.5. The app also uses arrays in several places(I understand that arrays need special handling in 0.5).

Comment: I'd recommend jumping straight to 0.6.0 (just released last week). It's a big step up from 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain automatic three way binding in 0.6, it's easy to do using the `$bind` method. In 0.3, you'd do something like:

```
angularFire(ref, $scope, 'model');
```

In 0.6, the same can be represented as:

```
$firebase(ref).$bind($scope, 'model');
```

Arrays are represented as objects in 0.6. You can pass `$scope.model` through the `orderByPriority` filter to get an array instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in model | orderByPriority">
```